# Peoplesoft html area value not returned

Tags: html, peoplesoft

I have a basic text input statement in a PeopleSoft html area on a custom page:

```
<input type="text" id="drivers" name="drivers" style="position:relative; width: 13em; left:3pt; top:3pt;color: #000000; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #FAFAD2;" size="13" placeholder="Example:N1234567" required="" maxlength="13" value="R291992929399">
```

The value R291992929399 shows up on the page as it's supposed to.

When submitting the value without changing the initial value of R291992929399, peoplecode returns a blank or null value.  I'm using the "%Request.GetParameter("drivers")" to access the value in the html area within Peoplecode.

The strange part is, if a messagebox is thrown on the page (checks the value to make sure it's not null, then produces an error message stating it can't be blank or null), the page is refreshed with the same value as before.  If I submit the value a second time, after clearing the error message, Peoplecode picks up the value R291992929399.

The only items on the peoplesoft page are: buttons to validate/save the page, employee id, company edit boxes, secondary page, and the html area.

Why does peoplecode not pickup the value when the page first loads?

Comment: Sorry the code didn't post - "<input type="text" id="drivers" name="drivers" style="position:relative; width: 13em; left:3pt; top:3pt;color: #000000; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; background-color: #FAFAD2;" size="13" placeholder="Example:N1234567" required="" maxlength="13" value="R291992929399">"

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please add your code to your question (preferably as a stack snippet), not in the comment section.

Comment: Why do you need a custom html area with input? Can't you use a delivered peopletools Field (if not for storage, you can use a work record)?

Answer (score 0):

The PeopleCode page backing data model is initialized on the app server. HTML is generated to match and display that model. When it is first generated, the value of that html area is just a string; no data is stored for the input field. When you do a partial post-back for a message box, the JavaScript post back send the current state of all inputs to the server therefore capturing the value.

The easiest way to get around this is use a derived record/field, and bind the field value into the HTML, that way that record is the backing model for the HTML area and will have the value for you to use in PeopleCode.

Use a HTML object in App designer, get the HTML Text and use `%bind(:1)` in the HTML, use `PAGERRECORD.HTML = GetHTMLText(HTML.MY_HTML, &rec.field.value);`

Does this help?